# async_read handler not called

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I try to make TCP asynchronous server, but I'm encountering some difficulties with async_read function. The handler async_read function is never called. I use this command to write on server's socket "nc -C 127.0.0.1 4242". Can you explain to me what I didn't understand or what mistakes I have made? Thanks for your help.

ChatSession.cpp

```
ChatSession::ChatSession(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
    : __socket(ioc)
{
}

ChatSession::pointer ChatSession::create(boost::asio::io_context& ioc)
{
    return pointer(new ChatSession(ioc));
}

tcp::socket& ChatSession::socket()
{
    return this->__socket;
}

void ChatSession::handle_start()
{
}

void ChatSession::start()
{
    std::string buffer = "Bienvenue\n";

    boost::asio::async_write(__socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
        boost::bind(&ChatSession::handle_start, shared_from_this()));
    readHeader();
}

void ChatSession::handleReadHeader(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    std::size_t byte_transferred)
{
    if (!error && this->__readMessage.decodeHeader()) {
        std::strcpy(__readMessage.getData(), __test.data());
        std::cout << __readMessage.getData() << std::endl;
        readBody();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Erreur" << std::endl;
    }
}

void ChatSession::readHeader()
{
    __test.resize(6);

    boost::asio::async_read(__socket,
        boost::asio::buffer(__test),
        boost::bind(
            &ChatSession::handleReadHeader,
            shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
 }
```

TcpServer.cpp:

```
TcpServer::TcpServer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, int port)
    : __acceptor (io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)))
{
    startAccept();
}


void TcpServer::startAccept()
{
    ChatSession::pointer newConnection = ChatSession::create(__io_context);

    __acceptor.async_accept(newConnection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&TcpServer::handle_accept, this, newConnection,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void TcpServer::handle_accept(ChatSession::pointer newConnection,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error) {
        newConnection->start();
        startAccept();
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int ac, char** av) {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        TcpServer server(io_context, 4242);
        io_context.run();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The code you posted does not compile for me (`ChatClient::readHeader` cuts off in the middle of statement). If I adapt your code to compile and comment out the `__readMessage.decodeHeader()` part in `handleReadHeader` (because I don't know what you want to do in that method), I can then receive messages of length six via netcat.

Comment: So the problem could be 1) the adaptions I had to made to get your code to compile differ from what the code looks like on your end 2) you send a message of size < 6. If you want `handleReadHeader` to trigger for shorter messages, then you would `async_read_some` instead 3) `decodeHeader` returns false. I cannot tell without seeing the definition of that method. Please clarify the exact behavior you want and the missing code.

Comment: Caution: Names with `__` are [reserved everywhere.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#:~:text=the%20identifiers%20with%20a%20double,reserved%20in%20the%20global%20namespace.) Using them technically results in unspecified behavior.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. @sehe is right, it is bad practice to use names starting with double underscores. A common convention is to use a single trailing underscore for member variables, another is to use "m_" at the start of member variables. However, this is unlikely to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: With this code I want to be able to communicate in a binary way with a client using qt, the goal is to make a light discord. I made some test when I remove the fact that the read is asynchronous everything works correctly. I have completely renamed my variables to avoid conflicts as you advised me. The headerDecoder() returns false if it does not correspond to certain condition like the size that I allotted to it. Thanks again for your help. To make this code I used the official doc of boost::asio : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp